# Spring Framework: is possible to create two beans of the same @Component without @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration, autowired

I'm just doing some experiments with Spring Web Apps in order to learn better how the framework works.

I usually create more beans of the same class using **@Configuration** class and **@Bean** methods and use **@Component** (and its derivates **@Controller**, **@Service**, **@Repository**) to let Spring inject **only a single bean** of the annotated class.

My question is, is that possible to create more beans of the same **@Component** class without using **@Configuration** and **@Bean**?

For instance having:

```
@Component
public class MyClass{}
```

and injecting this class in two different beans such as:

```
@Autowired MyClass beanA;
@Autowired MyClass beanB;
```

I've tried doing so and **OF COURSE** I got two instances pointing at the exact same bean in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring by default all beans have `singleton` scope unless specified otherwise. Hence you get the same instance when you Autowire it.

If you want a new instance you need to specify with `@Scope`

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyClass{}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very easy and immediate.